# Unable to install OS on M10 due to Device not found

Tags: boot, system-installation, ubuntu-touch, m10

I am trying to flash my Ubuntu Touch OTA-15 M10FHD.

I press the <kbd>power</kbd> & <kbd>volume up</kbd> buttons together to enter the boot meny and then I select the 'reboot to bootloader' option. When in the '=> FASTBOOT mode' screen, I then run a tool` to try and install an OS.

In the tool I get the following question:

```
Is your tablet in bootloader/fastboot mode now? [Y]
```

I press <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd>and get the following:

- Detecting Device
- **Device not found**
- Back to menu

This is where it all stops....

I have tried a number of times, in a number of ports, with the tablet in developer mode and with root permissions but still no luck. I know that the laptop can access the tablet as I can see files on my laptop when the tablet is connected.

I also tried to run another command in my laptop terminal (as below), but this was not successful either:

```
sudo ubuntu-device-flash --server=https://system-image.ubports.com/ touch --channel=ubports-touch/legacy --bootstrap --recovery-image=/home/uklaptop/Downloads/recovery-frieza.img
```

The output that I get here is this:

```
root@uklaptop:~# sudo ubuntu-device-flash --server=https://system-image.ubports.com/ touch --channel=ubports-touch/legacy --bootstrap --recovery-image=/home/uklaptop/Downloads/recovery-frieza.img
sudo: unable to resolve host uklaptop
2017/09/19 21:52:44 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2017/09/19 21:52:44 Device is |frieza|
2017/09/19 21:52:44 Flashing version 12 from ubports-touch/legacy channel and server https://system-image.ubports.com/ to device frieza
28.19 KB / 321.93 MB [] 0.01 % 46.90 KB/s 1h57m7s2017/09/19 21:52:46 Waiting for device to enter recovery mode ...
2.47 MB / 104.46 MB [__] 2.36 % 42.74 KB/s 40m43sFailed to enter Recovery
```

Is there any other setting that I need to activate or switch on my Ubuntu Touch tablet so that I can install a new OS or revert back if I need?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, however the main part of my question is the fact that I am unable to flush my Ubuntu Touch device (for whatever reason or build), due to the fact that it keep on coming up "Device not Found"  The last part of the whole question does state any other settings or anything that I need to activate. Put aside that I am going to play with UBPorts, I just want to know why I am unable to flush it in its current Ubuntu Touch state with OTA-15